# How can i troubleshoot this database error in phpmyadmin " Unknown database "

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am working on a food Restaurant Website and whenever I try to submit the data to the database it displays: **Unknown database foodies**. "foodies" is the name of my database. I have also gone inside the **phpmyadmin** to confirm that my database "foodies" is existing, I also confirmed that every columns are created correctly. But I don't know why it keeps on displaying **Unknown database foodies**. Please I need help. below is the code:

```
<?php 


      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
         // if button is clicked
         //1. This code will get the data from the form. 

       $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
       $username = $_POST['username'] ;
       $password = md5($_POST['password'] ); //password encrypted with md5


        // 2.the sql query will send the collected from the form to the database

       $sql = " INSERT INTO admin_1 SET
            full_name ='$full_name',
            username = '$username',
            password ='$password'

       ";

       // 3.This will execute the query and save it into the database

        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','<password>') or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 

        $db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn,'foodies') or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 

        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));        

       }

 ?>
```

Comment: check space in database name.

Comment: Please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, and next time, properly format your code _yourself_, instead of letting others do it for you.

Comment: Are you sure that foodies is database and not table ? Are you sure that from script perspective the db is accessible ? Like is the "localhost" true address of right sql server ? Does "root" user have access to the foodies database ? Maybe database got corrupted, you could try to do sql dump and recreate it. And do not use md5 hash for passwords it's crypthographically broken since 2008.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database?